# Arrived in Italy on Tourist Visa as a Spouse

Tags: marriage, eu-spouses

My South African husband has obtained an free Type C Visa as a spouse of an EU citizen for the duration of 90 days.

As soon as I obtain my residency status (Residenza) in Italy on the grounds of being a citizen we will then apply for an extension of his Visa or for a 'Carta di soggiorno'.

Am I right to assume that our financial status is irrilevant and that at least a two year Carta di soggiorno will be issued to him regardless of our employment status.

We did not register our marriage at the consulate in Jhb because I had been married previously and consequently got divorced in 2004 and did not register that marriage with the Consulate so now the Consulate asked me to do that marriage and divorce transcription first before I can register this marriage but because of a difficulty in obtaining my previous unabridged marriage certificate and divorce papers (I have the divorce decree) we decided to try and do it in baby steps while in Italy.

I please need advise regarding the difficulty of the application of a 'Carta di soggiorno' for my husband while only in possession of our unabridged marriage certificate but lacking the Apostille which I am awaiting a friend to send for me from South Africa.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I right to assume that our financial status is irrilevant and that
>   at least a two year Carta di soggiorno will be issued to him
>   regardless of our employment status

You're wrong, your financial status is relevant. The Questura (the Police) will ask you to submit the tax returns of the Italian citizen.

For example this year the amount of the social security allowance was set at 5.824,91 euros, so 5.824,91 euros is the minimum annual income that will have to prove who is applying for a residence card.

You don't need the divorce certificate in order to apply for a residence card, as soon as you get the Apostille you can ask the Questura for the residence card. Below are the the required documents:

- Passport or equivalent document in validity;
- Documents attesting to the relationship (the marriage certificate in this case? ;
- 4 recent photos of the person concerned;
- Stamp of € 16,00
- Tax returns (Dichiarazione dei redditi) or CUD (Certificato Unico Dipendente) of the Italian citizen.
- Declaration of maintenance signed by the Italian citizen.
- Certificate of residence or the application for registration of the Italian citizen at the local Commune, even in the case of an Italian citizen who moves from abroad.

**Edit**:

Here is the source from the [Official Police Website (Polizia di Stato)](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://questure.poliziadistato.it/statics/49/carta-di-soggiorno-per-familiare-extracomunitario-ex-art.-2-3-10-d.l.vo-30-2007.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiR_oXv78_UAhVkIMAKHR9EBx4QFggdMAA&usg=AFQjCNEWZ-xJS9F5kKj-f8TDu5tl044Rdg&sig2=gwRL9dmrLSQKNK-fVfnumg)

It says by the meaning in English:

> *Documentation confirming the availability of income by EU / Italian
>   citizen or, in the absence a statement on the reasons that led to the
>   absence of income with the indication of the period and the amount of
>   the latest income!*

[Another one here!](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://questure.poliziadistato.it/statics/37/carta-di-soggiorno-per-i-familiari-del-cittadino-comunitario.pdf%3Flang%3Dit&ved=0ahUKEwiR_oXv78_UAhVkIMAKHR9EBx4QFggpMAE&usg=AFQjCNGiD0_f-6Y9ef_g7RW47qbc3oS4gQ&sig2=o7--0-MibgOEotOxfCGI1A)

Comment: Are you certain of this?  Italy extends to the family of its citizens the same right of free movement that is enjoyed by family of other EU citizens, and there cannot be any financial test under the directive unless the couple are retired or otherwise economically inactive.

Comment: @Phoog yes, I'm certain because I was required to do that twice.. once for my my wife and again 3 months ago for my mother-in-land and yes I'm an Italian citizen!

Comment: Was that before or after 2007?

Comment: It was after 2007, I'm looking for a written official source I'll edit the answer when I find!

Comment: I don't doubt you, but I am curious how they justify that requirement in light of article 23 of [the Italian implementation of the freedom-of-movement directive](http://www.esteri.it/mae/normative/normativa_consolare/visti/d_lgs_30_2007.pdf).

Comment: @phoog the reason behind my reasoning is that I read that the actual residence "card" or Carta di Soggiorno is called a card because formally it is not a "permit" as in Pemesso di Soggiorno that would be "granted" but simply an official recognition of a pre-existing right.

Comment: @Phoog on Article 7 of Directive 2004/38/EC, ( https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do%3Furi%3DOJ:L:2004:158:0077:0123:en:PDF&ved=0ahUKEwi8iKrTvdHUAhVCC8AKHRoACYsQFggdMAA&usg=Afqjcnhppigahdutsruw4hfb5hzmisn5bw )It says ". All Union citizens shall have the right of residence on the territory of another Member State for a period of longer than three months if they: have sufficient resources for themselves and their family members not to become a burden on the social assistance system of the host Member State during the period."

Comment: The text you quote is one of four points in article seven, any one of which is by itself sufficient to confer the right of residence.  The first is being a worker or self employed.  If the EU or Italian citizen has a job, therefore, the authorities should not be asking for any proof of resources.

Comment: Well, I hope you checked the source I quoted above from the Police Website, also I believe to make things clear the OP should contact the local police of the province of Residency by phone or email, but I guarantee that's how it works here.

Comment: @SayedA. Could I use my savings amounting to more then Euro 5824.91 as proof of sufficient resources to sustain myself and my husband in the interim while I am looking for employement and furthermore the Income Tax returns to be submitted will be the ones submitted to the South Africa Tax Services for the last three years?

Comment: @Steph as I read on the Police Website​ only your husband's income or savings are relevant.  if you fail to submit an economic resource you might  get a temporary​ residency permit valid for 1 -2 years.

Comment: @SayedA. Does that mean that regardless of his income or proof thereof he will be allowed to remain in the country with me for either 1 or 2 years depending on the Questura decision? Is the temporary residency permit also called Carta di Soggiorno?

Comment: @Steph yes, in any case as an Italian/EU citizen's family member you can not be expelled from Italy even if your visa expires, the problem is not about staying in Italy,  it's about getting the  residency card, in order to get the residency card there are some requirements to fulfill. As from my understanding there is no such thing as a temporary Residency card, usually the residency card is valid for 5 years but the residency permit can be 6 months, a year and so on.. But I believe in your case you'll get some special treatments.

Comment: @SayedA. I've think you've misunderstood. The OP, Steph, _is_ an Italian citizen. The husband is South African. So Steph's income/job/finances matter, not the husband's.

Comment: @mkennedy thanks for the clarification, I thought Steph was the South African husband lol

Comment: @mkennedy you are quite right indeed

Comment: @SayedA. what do you mean by ''But I believe in your case you'll get some special treatments.'' ? Is it because of the age issue because my husband is close to 60 years old?

Comment: No, it's because you're an Italian/EU national, and your husband will be entitled as the same rights as you (an Italian citizen) even if he doesn't have the Residency card as long as you travel together in Europe... There are also other ways you can fix the financial income requirements​ for example if you have a family in Italy like your parents they can help you by submitting their tax returns to show that they will be able to accommodate you in Italy...

Comment: Hi @Stephania, how did things go for you? :) Update us if possible.

Comment: @SayedA. I have made an appointment at the local Questura (Caserta) for the 21 November in order for my husband to collect his Carta di Soggiorno. In the interim we managed to have the marriage trascribed at the local Comune (I gave them the Unabridged marriage certificate with the apostille all traslated by a registered translator) and they issued us with a certificate attesting it. Will keep you posted on the Carta di Soggiorno issue.

Comment: @SayedA Finger prints taken on the 21th as scheduled.No need for the Cessione di Fabbricato as we thought but gave my brother's CUD (I am on his family status) and my bank statement as proof of funds. Now to wait for Carta di Soggiorno for five years to be issued. Should be able to check online fourty days from now. Been to local "Comune'' for ''Residenza' which is given just with the Questura Receipt'. The Questura was extremely helpful as well as the local Comune. So far so good.

Comment: @SayedA my husband will get his ID Book tomorrow from the local Comune

Comment: Stephania thanks for keeping us updated and best of luck to you. :)

Comment: @SayedA my husband has received a Carta di Soggiorno Per Motivi Familiari valid for four years (until 2022) in record time. Thanks to the site for all the assistance given.